# How to track the user after login to the website?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Below is the code to track the how many guest visited my page?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var _gaq = _gaq || [];
        _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-18841631-1']);

    _gaq.push(['_setCustomVar',1,'Status','Logged-in',1]);

    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

    (function() {
            var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
                ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
                var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
         })();
    </script>
```

How to track the user after login to the website?

To track the user after login what all are the steps have to follow..plese guide me...

Answer (score 0):

The best way for user tracking after his login is session . Just create and maintain session variables according to your need when user successfully signed in.

Comment: I maintained in session. 
If login is successfull means the value in the _setcustomvar should change to "Logged in" otherwise it should be in "Logged out"